# The for while statement won't repeat

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I have been on this code for about all day and I can't figure out which curly brace (`{`) is missing or the code to repeat the process is not well placed. Thanks in advance for your help. I feel like a loser as I am working with classes and methods and I can't even figure out my `{` brace issue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChoHan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        final int MAX_ROUNDS = 5 ;
        String player1Name ;
        String player2Name ;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        do

        {
        System.out.println(" Enter the first player name :");
        player1Name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the second player name :");
        player2Name = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println(" Would you like to play again ?");
        System.out.println(" Enter y for yes or n for no ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        char repeat = input.charAt(0);

        while (repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y');


        Dealer dealer = new Dealer();

        Player player1 = new Player(player1Name);
        Player player2 = new Player(player2Name);

        for(int round = 0; round <MAX_ROUNDS; round++)
        {
            System.out.println("-----------------------");
            System.out.printf(" Now playing round %d.\n",round + 1);

            dealer.RollDice();

            player1.makeGuess();
            player2.makeGuess();

            roundResult(dealer,player1,player2);
        }

            displayGrandWinner(player1,player2);



       public static void roundResult(Dealer dealer, Player player1, Player player2)
       {
           System.out.printf(" The dealer roll %d and %d.\n", dealer.getDie1Value(),
                   dealer.getDie2Value());
           System.out.printf("Results : %s\n", dealer.getchorOrHan());

           checkGuess(player1, dealer);
           checkGuess(player2, dealer);
       }

       public static void checkGuess(Player player, Dealer dealer)
       {
           final int POINTS_TO_ADD = 1 ;
           String guess = player.getGuess();
           String choHanResult = dealer.getchorOrHan();

           System.out.printf("The Player %s guessed %s.\n", player.getName(),
                player.getGuess());

           if( guess.equalsIgnoreCase(choHanResult))
           {
               player.addPoints(POINTS_TO_ADD);
               System.out.printf("Awarding %d points(s)to %s\n", POINTS_TO_ADD,
                player.getName());
           }
       } 
        public static void displayGrandWinner(Player player1, Player player2) 
        {


            System.out.println("--------------------------");
            System.out.println(" Game over !. Here are the results:");
            System.out.printf("%s : %d points.\n", player1.getName(), player1.getPoints());
            System.out.printf("%s : %d points.\n", player2.getName(), player2.getPoints());

            if(player1.getPoints() > player2.getPoints())
                System.out.println(player1.getName() + " is the Grand Winner!");
            else if(player2.getPoints() > player1.getPoints())
                System.out.println(player2.getName() + " is the Grand Winner!");
            else
                System.out.println(" Both players are tied!");


        }
        }
```

Comment: It is asking me to add a { at the displayGrandWinner method but even when I add it it is still asking to add it. I know for sure that I did not place the for and while statement  properly in the code

Comment: `while (repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y');` you don't want a ; here. It either never loops or loops infinitely.

Comment: Did you try auto-indenting it in your GUI?

Comment: @AndyTurner or possibly, they need a `}` right before that.

Comment: @JiriTousek oh sure. I see. Yes, could be that instead. Except that would put `repeat` out of scope for the condition.

Comment: If I remove the ; it complaints that Dealer cannot be resolve to a variable.

Comment: Looks like there's some more brackets missing, though.

Comment: I tried everything it just won't work

Comment: possibly Jiri but where to add them ?

Comment: @Freddy53 it is hard to say what to do, because we don't know what it *should* do.

Comment: I know Andy I was asking myself that same question that's why I post the code at the very beginning . I tried the end but it does not work either. I can repeat without for ? But how ?

Comment: You are trying to fix compile error or logical error ?

Comment: The code posted is associated with 3 other classes. I made some programs with the for and while statements to repeat the code if the user agrees "Y" but with this program it is more complex. The program works properly without the for while. I just want to add that option for the user after the program has given the results. logical error Drowny

Comment: Carlos when I add } it complaints that repeat cannot be resolved as a variable. Maybe the logical mistake is above the while ? And it asks a { at displayGrandWinner(player1,player2); , even if I add it it keep posting that same requirement

Comment: I added some code to answers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Can u try this ? I added to logical solution to code.I changed only starting game and ending game properties's lines.

```
public class ChoHan {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int MAX_ROUNDS = 5;
    String player1Name;
    String player2Name;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    char repeat;
    do
    {
        System.out.println(" Enter the first player name :");
        player1Name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the second player name :");
        player2Name = keyboard.nextLine();

        Dealer dealer = new Dealer();

        Player player1 = new Player(player1Name);
        Player player2 = new Player(player2Name);

        for (int round = 0; round < MAX_ROUNDS; round++) {
            System.out.println("-----------------------");
            System.out.printf(" Now playing round %d.\n", round + 1);

            dealer.RollDice();

            player1.makeGuess();
            player2.makeGuess();

            roundResult(dealer, player1, player2);
        }

        displayGrandWinner(player1, player2);

        System.out.println(" Would you like to play again ?");
        System.out.println(" Enter y for yes or n for no ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        repeat = input.charAt(0);
    } while (repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y');

}

public static void roundResult(Dealer dealer, Player player1, Player player2) {
    System.out.printf(" The dealer roll %d and %d.\n", dealer.getDie1Value(),
            dealer.getDie2Value());
    System.out.printf("Results : %s\n", dealer.getchorOrHan());

    checkGuess(player1, dealer);
    checkGuess(player2, dealer);
}

public static void checkGuess(Player player, Dealer dealer) {
    final int POINTS_TO_ADD = 1;
    String guess = player.getGuess();
    String choHanResult = dealer.getchorOrHan();

    System.out.printf("The Player %s guessed %s.\n", player.getName(),
            player.getGuess());

    if (guess.equalsIgnoreCase(choHanResult)) {
        player.addPoints(POINTS_TO_ADD);
        System.out.printf("Awarding %d points(s)to %s\n", POINTS_TO_ADD,
                player.getName());
    }
}

public static void displayGrandWinner(Player player1, Player player2) {


    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println(" Game over !. Here are the results:");
    System.out.printf("%s : %d points.\n", player1.getName(), player1.getPoints());
    System.out.printf("%s : %d points.\n", player2.getName(), player2.getPoints());

    if (player1.getPoints() > player2.getPoints())
        System.out.println(player1.getName() + " is the Grand Winner!");
    else if (player2.getPoints() > player1.getPoints())
        System.out.println(player2.getName() + " is the Grand Winner!");
    else
        System.out.println(" Both players are tied!");


  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Drowny! It solve my issue ! I have been on this for so many hours. Do you think I should continue programming in Java ? I started about little bit more than 1 month and I feel discouraged for not be able to solve a do while issue ?

Comment: Dont be afraid to learn but you have to learn with basic algorithms and types of programming. In this problem, you used do while loop in wrong way. Firstly learn which do you need to use , and some works on types, loops or anything to coding. This thinks not for Java, u can apply to all languages. Dont stop go ahead.

Comment: Ok Drowny thanks for the advices. I appreciated your help with this problem

Comment: @Freddy53 Don't stop. We all have been there. Each time you make an error, you'll learn. It's frustrating in the beginning, but it will become easier!

Comment: I'm glad to help you.

Comment: Ok Modus I appreciate your words of encouragements ! I will keep learning.